# Is it possible to simply select an image to kick off a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, json-formatting, power-automate

I have an picture library setup on a site collection.

I’m looking to simply have a user select an image from it to trigger a email notification that would relay the image properties or title, is this  possible to do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using designer workflow or microsoft flow/power automate?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I was hoping that I would have been able to do it with oob workflow, but quickly found out that I couldn't. I was able to do it with power automate. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**.

You can achieve this type of requirements using **[Microsoft Flow/Power Automate](https://flow.microsoft.com)** in SharePoint Online.

Also, you can use JSON formatting capabilities in SharePoint Online to run your flow right from list view.

**Reference**: [Create a button to launch a Flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-a-button-to-launch-a-flow).